# Given $X$ a metric space, $S \subset X$ and $S_\epsilon = \{x \in X: d(x, X \setminus S) \geq \epsilon \}$ find $int(S)$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Given $X$ a metric space $S \subset X$ and $S_\epsilon = \{x \in X: d(x, X \setminus S) \geq \epsilon \}$. I am trying to show that $int(S) = \bigcup_{\epsilon >0} S_\epsilon$.

I am trying to prove the statement the following way. Let $x \in  \bigcup_{\epsilon >0} S_\epsilon$, I want to show that there is some $r > 0$ such that $B(x,r) \subseteq  \bigcup_{\epsilon >0} S_\epsilon$. But shouldn’t $r$ be infinitely large in order for this to happen? If I am not wrong, the sets $S_\epsilon$ are closed, can I somehow use that to prove what I want?

Comment: Why would $r$ need to be infinitely large?

Comment: Because $d(x, X \setminus S) \geq \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon >0$. So I would need $r > \epsilon$. But I am probably thinking it wrong.

Comment: Note that $S_\epsilon \subset S$.

Comment: But isn’t $S_\epsilon \cap S^c = \emptyset$?

Comment: That is the same thing.

Comment: @copper.hat You are right, how dumb of me. But how does this help me? 

I know that $int(S)$ is the union of all open subsets of $S$. But, if I am not wrong, then $S_\epsilon$ are open, because $S_\epsilon^c = \{x \in X: d(x, X \setminus S) < \epsilon\}$ is open.

Comment: Show that if $x \in S^\circ$ then $x \in \cup_{ \epsilon >0} S_ \epsilon$ and show that if $x \in S_\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0$ then $x \in S^\circ$.

Comment: @copper.hat Indeed that is what I need to show. If $x \in S^{\circ}, \exists r > 0: B(x,r) \subseteq S$. So $B(x,r) \cap S^c = \emptyset$, so $d(x,y) \geq \epsilon  \ \forall y \in S^c, \epsilon > 0$. Then $d(x,X \setminus S) \geq \epsilon$ and $x \in \bigcup_{\epsilon > 0} S_\epsilon$. Is this right?

Comment: That direction is correct.

Comment: Now if $x \in \bigcup_{\epsilon > 0} S_\epsilon$ then $\forall \epsilon > 0, d(x,X \setminus S) \geq \epsilon.$ In order to show that $x \in S^{\circ}$ I want some $r > 0$ such that $B(x,r) \cap S^c = \emptyset$, what value of $r$ would work?

Comment: You lost me with the last comment. All you know is that $x \in S_\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0$, I do not understand where you got the for all $\epsilon>0$ from.

Comment: @copper.hat You are right, since $x$ belongs to $\bigcup_{\epsilon > 0} S_\epsilon$ then $x \in S_\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon$ rather than for every $\epsilon$ as I had wrongly stated. What is left for me to show would be that $\exists r > 0$ such that $B(x,r) \subseteq S$, i.e $B(x,r) \cap S^c = \emptyset$. Would $r = d(x,X \setminus S)$ work? This last bit has got me kind of confused.

Comment: If $x \in S_\epsilon$ then show that $B(x,\epsilon) \subset S$.

Comment: Given $y \in B(x,\epsilon)$ we know that $d(x,y) < \epsilon$ and that $d(x, X \setminus S) \geq \epsilon$. How can I conclude that $y \in S$?

Comment: Show that $y \ne c$ for any $c \in S^c$.

Comment: Use the triangle inequality.

Comment: You mean I should use $d(y, X \setminus S) \geq d(x,y) - d(x, X \setminus S)$? If I get to $d(y, X \setminus S) \geq \epsilon$, I guess that $y \notin S$ but I don't see this from that inequality

Comment: Why don't you try what I suggested.

Comment: What do you mean? I tried the triangle inequality, but I don't see how $d(x,y) \leq d(x, X \setminus S) + d(y, X \setminus S)$ gets me to $y \notin S^c, i.e \ y \neq c \ \forall c \in S^c$.

Comment: You need to try a little more.

Comment: I think I need to conclude that $d(y, X \setminus S) \geq \epsilon$ though.

Comment: This is the same as showing that $\overline{S} = \bigcap_{\epsilon > 0} S'_\epsilon$,  where $S'_\epsilon = \{x \in X: d(x,S) < \epsilon\}$ I believe. Maybe try that? @copper.hat correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Suppose $x \in S_\epsilon$. Then I claim that $B(x,\epsilon) \subset S$. Suppose $y \in B(x,\epsilon)$ and $z \in S^c$. Then $d(x,y) < \epsilon$ and $d(x,z) \ge \epsilon$. Hence $d(y,z) \ge d(x,z)-d(x,y)>0$. Hence $y \in S$.

Comment: Did you sort out your proof?

Comment: Indeed, thanks for your help!